# Drawing convexHull in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, contour

So I am trying to draw the convexHull from a contour in python, however when i print the image it is not changing.

```
roi=mask[y:y+h,x:x+w]
roi = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(roi,None,15,15,7,21)
hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
cv2.drawContours(roi,[hull],0,(147,0,255),2)
cv2.imshow(str(i),roi)
blank_image[y:y+h,x:x+w] = roi
```

However, the images that show are the exact same if I did not include the code. I looked online, but cannot seem to find the answer.
Here is a sample Image:[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Anyone know? Still cannot find a fix.

Comment: can you upload the image you are working with?

Comment: @JeruLuke It is many images, each of the images are thresholded out. I am creating an OCR platform, so each ROI is a different character.

Comment: @JeruLuke I just added a sample image. That is what it would generally look like; however the whitespace around the character is expanded a bit more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I used the following code to obtain convex hull for the image given by you:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('2.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, 0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,2,1)
print len(contours)
cnt = contours[0]

hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt,returnPoints = False)
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt,hull)

for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
    s,e,f,d = defects[i,0]
    start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
    end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
    far = tuple(cnt[f][0])
    cv2.line(img,start,end,[0,255,0],2)
    cv2.circle(img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

cv2.imshow('img',img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Since contours are based on the white region in an image, I was able to obtain two ***types*** of contours by altering **line 5** in the code.

***CASE 1 :***

I was able to obtain this: [image]

***CASE 2 :***
Now when I change the **fifth** line in the code segment, I obtain this: [image] when I invert the binary image `ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, 1)`

This is because in **case 1** the contour was found based on this image [image]

Now in **case 2** the contour was found based on this image [image]

As you can see, contours are found based on the **white** region in the binary image.

Hope this helps.

I used [THIS LINK](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html) for obtaining the code and for reference.