# Is there any way to export polygon coordinates of the mask of a Yolo v7 model?

Tags: python, mask, image-segmentation, yolov7

I am training a Yolo v7 model on a dataset that I annotated, using [Wong Kin Yiu's](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) repository. The goal is to create a mask of the heart during surgery. I have had success with the model creating the mask of the heart, but as far as I am aware, I can only export the bounding box coordinates. I need to be able to export the polygon coordinates of the mask.

I tried to look through the source code and mask creating functions to find if there was a parameter I needed to export this. I could not find anything; only bounding box data.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mask.

All that remains is to
[turn](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html)
it into a
[convex hull](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656).
This is explained in many places, including
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508775/drawing-convexhull-in-opencv-python).